# Nuxt.js app behind nginx reverse-proxy loading multiple pages at once

Tags: vue.js, nginx, reverse-proxy, nuxt.js

I've a nuxt.js app behind nginx reverse proxy. The nginx conf file looks like this:

```
  server {
    listen 80;
    # Match *.lvh.me
    server_name  ~^(?<user>.+)\.lvh\.me$;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/sites/$user$uri$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~* \.(?:js|css|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|svg)$ {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }

  }
```

As you can see I'm mapping all my site subdomains to a specific path on my site and it is working fine. I'm also mapping all assets to be loaded from the root (because otherwise it throws a 404 error).

The only issue I'm facing is the whenever I visit a subdomain `e.g subdomain.lvh.me` it loads two pages on top of each other, the original page from subdomain root (which is expected) but also the page from the main domain root `i.e. lvh.me` (which is not expected).

Can you please checkout my conf file to see if I'm doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

So I've encountered this issue and what I did to fix it was to not rely on Nginx's `root` nor `proxy_pass`. Instead, I used a location block with an alias and a `try_files` inside like so:

```
location ^~ / {
        alias /path/to/dist;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html = 404;
}
```